# Custom Scaling in Julia PyPlot

Tags: matlab, julia, octave

The following is Octave/Matlab code

```
 x=linspace(0,1,100);
 y=linspace(0,1,100);
 [X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
 Z=-(X.^2+Y.^2)+1;

 figure(1)
 surf(X.^6,Y.^6,Z);
 shading interp;view([0 90]);
 axis tight
 colorbar;
```

What is the equivalent using PyPlot in Julia?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

```
import Plots
x = range( 0, 1; length=100 );
y = range( 0, 1; length=100 );
f(x,y) = - ( x .^ (2/6) .+ y .^ (2/6) ) .+ 1;
Plots.surface( x, y, f; viewangle=(0,90) )
```

http://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/

Comment: The axes that you defined are linear, but the axes I defined were not.   Since pcolormesh does not respect nonlinear axes I was trying to simulate a flat pcolormesh-type picture using surf (hence the top down view angle) but surf and surface don't generate a truly flat picture so I posted this question.  I ended up using interpolate to redefine the Z on linear axes, and then I just used pcolormesh anyway.  If I have time later I may revise the question and answer to reflect what I learned. Thanks for your help :) !!

Comment: Ah, right, sorry, I failed to spot that. I should point out that the scale is still linear, you're just amending the grid. Which is equivalent to modifying the function (as per the update). But yes I know what you mean.

Comment: yes, correct, good clarification thanks :)